# Retrieve const string value from .elf binary via variable name using command line utility?

Tags: debugging, binaryfiles, elf

Consider the following `main.c`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

const char greeting[] = "hello world";

int main() {
    printf("%s!\n", greeting);
    return 0;
}
```

I compiled this in Ubuntu with:

```
gcc -g main.c -o main.exe
```

I would like to retrieve the value of the variable named `greeting`; considering it is `const`, it won't change, so it should be possible to retrieve the value "hello world" from the executable.

Basically, I can see the variable name in the binary using:

```
$ readelf -p .rodata main.exe | grep hello
  [     8]  hello world
```

... and I can see the value using:

```
$ readelf -s main.exe | grep greeting
    59: 0000000000002008    12 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT   18 greeting
```

I could try parsing the output of `readelf -s` and `readelf -p` to get what I want (retrieve the value of the variable named `greeting`), but I'm pretty sure I'll mess it up.

So is there some combination of switches of bintools utilities (or any command line program, really), which would perform the equivalent of the following pseudocode:

```
$ [tool] --get-value-of-variable-name greeting --program=main.exe
"hello world"
```

or even:

```
$ [tool] --verbose --get-value-of-variable-name greeting --program=main.exe
The constant value of the variable "greeting" in `main.exe` is:
"hello world"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there some combination of switches of bintools utilities (or any command line program, really), which would perform the equivalent of the following pseudocode:

Sure:

- you need to find the section in which the symbol resides, and the address within that section, and the length of data, and
- you need to find where in the file the section itself starts, and
- you need to dump length bytes from the right offset in the file.

Getting this all together (my file has slightly different data from yours):

```
readelf -Ws main.exe | grep greeting
    29: 0000000000002008    12 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT   17 greeting

readelf -WS main.exe | grep '\[17\]'
  [17] .rodata           PROGBITS        0000000000002000 002000 000019 00   A  0   0  8
```

This tells me that I need to dump `12` bytes (actually 11, since I don't want the terminating `\0`), starting at offset `0x2000 + (0x2008 (symbol address) - 0x2000 (section address))`.

```
dd if=main.exe bs=1 skip=$((0x2008)) count=11 2>/dev/null
hello world
```

Now, parsing this data out from `readelf` output is more trouble than it's worth -- it's much easier to write a simple `C++` program to produce the desired output. Using [ELFIO](https://github.com/serge1/ELFIO) should make this very easy.

Comment: Many thanks, @EmployedRussian - fantastic answer; and sorry for the late accept!